# Umlaut chars not well handled in JSP input form

Tags: java, jsp, character-encoding

After submitting an input form (JSP) in one server I can correctly see umlaut chars while in the other not and are replaced with strange one. The web.xml correctly set the encoding filter for utf8. What can be the issue? Are maybe JVM variables in play here? App is running on Pivotal Clound Foundry.

Comment: So written UTF-8 text in the JSP reaches the client, but client not always submits UTF-8 fields. `<form action="..." accept-charset="UTF-8">` will ensure that UTF-8 is responded, and not something like `&#253;`. JSP  There are other things like JSP page encoding. General JVM parameters are not concerned.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for reply. But why in one server works and in the other not?